# How to I check whether a process is started or not in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, process, processbuilder

I have a question related to Process creation in java. The main scenario is that I want to show a progress bar/spin loader until the process gets started
Below is the code for starting a process using java.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("python", filename);
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

How exactly I will know that this process is started.
Thanks

Comment: What do you really want? `start()` starts your process, you don't have to wait.

Comment: After that code, why do you think it wouldn't have started?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès There's 3,4 seconds delay while process gets start

Comment: @AndyTurner The process gets start after 3,4 seconds and I want to show a waiting progress bar to the user until process starts

Comment: What does it exactly means 3/4 seconds while starting? Are you taliing about responsiveness of the process? That is not the same thing. `start()` starts it, it may be possible that the given process is not responsive for a while then.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès yeah may the case is that the process is not responsive for 3,4 seconds as I'm trying to run a python script on button click. That python script access the webcam so may be due to that script I get the process in run after 3/4 seconds

Comment: "Your process is not responsive" is a characteristic of what you're running.  It seems to be your code that's being run. Have it emit some indication that it is "ready", according to your definition of ready.  Or poll it until it responds.

Answer (score 1):

The `ProcessBuilder#start()` method starts the process as soon as you call the method. If the executable file is not found it throws `IOException`. If everything is ok, your process is surely started. Yes, the process may take some time to get loaded but it is the time taken by the process to response. It gets started immediately.

Try running notepad by this code

```
System.out.println("Starting...");
new ProcessBuilder("notepad").start();
```

As soon as `Starting...` is printed you will see the Notepad window popping up.
Again it depends on your processor speed. A lightweight application like Notepad may pop out immediately, but a heavyweight application like Android Studio may take some time to pop out. But whatever the process maybe it starts immediately.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I made a solution for my problem.
I used the thread class with process to perform my required task
Here's what I have done

```
Loader loader = new Loader();
        loader.setVisible(true);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                private int count = 4;
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (count <= 0) {
                            loader.setVisible(false);
                            ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                        } else {
                            count--;
                        }
                    }
                });
                timer.start();
            }
        });
        t1.start();
```

Where Loader is my simple class having a gif in panel to show for 4 seconds